# kendoToolBar with display:none attribute doesn't wok on resize screen

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, toolbar

i have this simple [exmaple](http://dojo.telerik.com/ijajA) of Kendo UI toolbar,

```
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
  items: [
    {
      type: "buttonGroup",
      attributes: {
        style: "display:none",
      },
      buttons: [
        { text: "foo" },
        { text: "bar" },
        { text: "baz" }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

As you can see, when run this part of code, toolbar dotn display nothing, because has attribute "display:none", but if you change the SCREEN SIZE, minimaze,maximaze, or resize seems like this attribute leaves, and display everything.

IS THIS BUG OF TELERIK KENDO?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add '!important':

```
attributes: {
        style: "display:none !important",
      }
```

Comment: have you tried a least to test your answer? i guess no... no this doesnt not work